# Documentation changes by a diamond moderator go undetected

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, moderators, documentation-proposals

Diamond moderators may need to remove or edit content if needed, without review. That is fine.

**But their changes do not appear in tab=proposedchanges, subtab=approved.** [At least I assume they should be there as they are implicitly approved.]

This bug prevents me from reviewing these changes (they are also just humans) and eventually proposing improvements/flagging if necessary.

Example: a moderator removed an important example due to plagiarism. Nobody notices... Instead, one shall be able to notice it and eventually flag for "missing example" or re-add it myself with original content.

Comment: "*without review*" "*This bug prevents me from reviewing*" As you yourself point out, the lack of review is a *feature*, not a bug.

Comment: Hmm. These do (or at least should) show up under Activities, but I see your point. The level of noise in that section is definitely going to be higher than in the proposed changes section. I don't know if I'd classify it as a feature request or a bug, but either way I agree that we should surface these edits - especially if we introduce a self-approve privilege level later.

Comment: Not to mention the original contributer might want to know the reason for their contribution suddenly being gone/modified.

Comment: @NicolBolas The lack of review to _be approved_ is the feature. The bug is the inability to easily track the auto-approvals...

Comment: @AdamLear Activity currently only displays deletions when they were undeleted later on… Also, it links to the topic, and not the edit, making it not extremely helpful for me.

Comment: @AdamLear Quick reminder about this as I think this one got even more important now with the self-approve level for silver/gold badges. [I suppose it's a rather quick fix, would be much appreciated if you could include it.]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out we weren't setting `ReviewableDate` (which is the timestamp of when a proposed change went into review) on self-approved changes. That's been corrected and data fixed up retroactively, so self-approved changes by moderators and badge holders will now appear under the Proposed Changes/Approved tab in the tag dashboard.

Comment: "self-approved"?? Why on earth would changes that go through without review be marked as "approved by the guy who made this change" instead of "approved by system"?

Comment: That's effectively the same in this case. Just wording here...

Comment: @dorukayhan Eh? Tracking `ApprovalDate` at the DB level isn't the same as saying "This change was approved by X." These changes are annotated so it's clear what happened: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuHbf.png.